# how to handle `Type | boolean` return values in typescript and error checking / tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, types

I have a function that can return a found object, or fail.
What's the best value to return in the failure case? `{}|null|undefined|false`

The problem is my test rely on this object, but I get typescript warnings as `false` could also be returned

```
    const actualResult: ActionResult | boolean = await findAndRunAction(evt)
    if (actualResult) {
      expect(actualResult.klass).toBe('room')
```

where

```
function findAndRunAction(): ActionResult | false { 
// if found
return obj: ActionResult
// else
return false
 }
```

typescript is smart enough to know the value must be `truthy` but that *should* be when I am returning an instance of the full object, not just `true`.

I could throw an error, or the other way would be to always return the same object type but just add a `ok: true|false` field into the object. That seems a bit excessive, but I guess it does mean I always only have one return type...

Suggestions for good patterns to use with this in TS please!

[image: ts problems]

[image: failing test]

The compiler fails, but the actual test is passing.

Update: I did something like this:

```
// define all the other fields as optional

interface ActionResult {
  ok: boolean
  doc?: ActionData
  events?: string[]
  klass?: string
}

// so I can just return an empty obj in fail case

    return {
      ok: false
    }
```

I don't like this so much as it gives less rigidity on the actual type with all these options.

Comment: I think more obviously is to use ```ActionResult | null``` as a return type of ```findAndRunAction``` function. Also I don't understand why you named your checking function as ```...AndRunAction```, because it doesn't run anything, its responsibility is to find and nothing else. After you could check for result like this ```if (actualResult !== null) ...```.

Comment: how would returning `null` make things easier? as opposed to `undefined` say? this is just the minimal example, not my actual code, which does do stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could go about this, as you're using a union type with a primitive, the simplest solution would be to `typeof` check for the boolean e.g.

```
  if (typeof actualResult !== 'boolean') {
```

The compiler is smart enough to narrow down the options to the single `ActionResult`. This works for primitives but only provides a shallow check so objects won't be properly differentiated.

Additionally this is quite unwieldy if you have more than two return types as you have to exclude each and everyone one (and chaining `else if` won't continually narrow down the types left you'd have to nest them inside which will become a confusing `else if` hellscape), so a (still not perfect) option is to implement your own typeof check with generics and property checking.

I got this snippet from [how-to-use-typescript-type-guards](https://rangle.io/blog/how-to-use-typescript-type-guards/) and it's been handy a few times:

```
export const isOfType = <T>(
  varToBeChecked: any,
  propertyToCheckFor: keyof T,
): varToBeChecked is T =>
  (varToBeChecked as T)[propertyToCheckFor] !== undefined;
```

This little utility function will allow you to adjust your test to be:

```
test('should test', () => {
  const actualResult = findAndRunAction(false);
  if (isOfType<ActionResult>(actualResult, 'klass')) {
    expect(actualResult.klass).toBe('room');
  }
});
```

This will compile, but it is not perfect. We assume that `klass` is a unique property between the return types of your function, and it requires insight into the properties of the type you're checking for so its not a very abstracted solution, but might be helpful in some simple cases where the return is two differently structured objects.

In the case of something simple like this I'd probably just opt for the first option, but decide based on your needs :)

Comment: hmm thanks! well I learned something today! But that advanced use of Generics seems quite complex to future me (and now me haha). Do you think there's anything inherently bad with my technique of always returning the same type and just adding a true/false field into the object? Seems more consistent and not have to do these type of gymnastics

Comment: Glad to help! Well I if you're using typescript I would recommend getting familiar with generics because they're great! But in this case no theres nothing wrong with your technique, the best code is firstly code that works, secondly code that is human readable - don't obfuscate your intention with code by trying to make it look 'smart' (e.g. most array.reduce uses are pretty awful imo) - so go with what works for you! I added options to give you informed choices. Also if my answer helped and you have no outstanding issues with this question feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: the answer is useful, tho not quite simple! √ anyway and thanks